# Angular 6 - changes in existing files are not detecting when the server is not running

Tags: node.js, angular, angular6

I am working on a angular project that i cloned form git. When I modified some code and started dev server it doesn't detect changes made, but when i saved file again, while server is still running the changes are detected...can any one help me to resolve the issue...

Comment: Are you using Visual studio Code for IDE

Comment: You're using some IDE/text editor (probably VSCode as @V5NXT states) with autosave option disabled

Comment: yes I am using VSCode, but my problem is with initial start it doesn't detect earlier saved changes

Comment: it's due to git.

Comment: I asked because I normally get unsaved data while using Vscode